# Find all duplicates for a particular issue

Tags: jira, jql

I have an issue which has duplicates and "duplicate by" already linked to the issue. I am trying a jql query that will list all those duplicates. 
Lets say the issue ID is "10000" and the duplicate issues are "20000" and "30000". When I run the jql like this

```
key in (10000) AND (issue in hasLinks("duplicates") or issue in hasLinks("is duplicated by"))
```

I get the result set that shows me only 10000. How can I modify my jql to give me 20000 and 30000 in the result set.

Comment: `in (10000, 20000, 30000)...` isn't what you're looking for?  [From Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver072/advanced-searching-fields-reference-829092671.html)

Comment: Well, in this case, I know the answers as 20000 and 30000 but I am looking for a general jql query that will list duplicates and duplicated by issues given a particular issue.

Comment: So, to clarify, you don't want ID matches to be explicitly found - you're looking for only the duplicates of any ID (not necessarily 10000)?

Comment: Yes given an issue , i want to only find the its duplicates and its duplciated by in my search result. From a display perspective, i think i can do an "OR key in (10000)" to see all 3 issues in the result (for this specific example)

Comment: Any idea on how i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really spend some time looking at the [Advanced searching](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACORECLOUD/Advanced+searching) page, it has information about a lot of functionality that's hidden at first.

For your use case check [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracorecloud/advanced-searching-functions-reference-765593719.html#Advancedsearching-functionsreference-linkedIssueslinkedIssues()) out:

JQL:

```
key in linkedIssues([parentIssue], "duplicates")
```

and

```
key in linkedIssues([parentIssue], "is duplicated by")`
```

You need to run both queries.